# Pandas HDF5 Column Select not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe saved to HDF5 as a table, but my where clause goes haywire when the select statement has floats (it does work with string). Pandas 0.12 with latest Numpy on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
>>> dim_hdf.select(store_name)
    desc  rowid
0    NaN    NaN
1    1.0      1
2    2.0      2
3    3.0      3
4    4.0      4
5    5.0      5
6    6.0      6
7    7.0      7
8    8.0      8
9    9.0      9
10  10.0     10

>>> dim_hdf.select(store_name).dtypes
desc      object
rowid    float64
dtype: object

>>> dim_hdf.root.dim_29.table
/dim_29/table (Table(11,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "desc": StringCol(itemsize=4, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1),
  "rowid": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=2)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (3276,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "rowid": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "desc": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
```

But the selecting goes wrong (and does work for strings):

```
>>> dim_hdf.select(store_name, where=[('rowid','=', 1.0)])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [desc, rowid]
Index: []

>>> dim_hdf.select(store_name, where=[('rowid','=', '1.0')])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [desc, rowid]
Index: []

>>> dim_hdf.select(store_name, where=[('desc','=', '1.0')])
  desc  rowid
1  1.0      1
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Kind regards,

Carst

Comment: what version of PyTables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am almost 100% sure this is a very subtle bug in PyTables (>= 2.3). see here: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/282

Seems that when selecting on a float columns, that *has* an index, AND
there is a `np.nan` in the first (0th) element, selection does not work.

When the `np.nan` is not in the 0th position or there is no index, then
selection works normally.

The workaround is to either: write a 'dummy' first row that has values, or to write
with no index for that column.

```
In [13]: df = DataFrame(dict(cols = range(6), values = range(6)), dtype='float64')

In [14]: df['cols'] = (df['cols']+10).apply(str)

In [15]: df.iloc[0] = np.nan

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
   cols  values
0   NaN     NaN
1  11.0       1
2  12.0       2
3  13.0       3
4  14.0       4
5  15.0       5

# write w/o the index on that particular column
In [16]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',table=True,data_columns=True,index=['cols'])

In [17]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where=[('values','>',2.0)])
Out[17]: 
   cols  values
3  13.0       3
4  14.0       4
5  15.0       5
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I will try it tonight to see if it creates the issue. I think i can circumvent it by replacing NaN by an unique value (it's a reporting dimension, not a measure).

Comment: FYI, pytables 3.1 is now out; and this bug is fixed!